# posgres upsert with unknown/random id from client?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

Hello i'm trying to insert/update some rows with upsert but the id on the insert part is unknown.

what i mean is this

```
INSERT INTO task (id,name,description,completed)
VALUES
--update
(20,'Do stuff','Stuff to do...',false), 
(21,'Do stuff','Stuff to do...',false), 
--insert
(unknown_or_random_id,'Do stuff','Stuff to do...',false), 
(unknown_or_random_id,'Do stuff','Stuff to do...',false), 
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
SET name= excluded.name etc....
```

basically the array i get from the client contains random ids for the new items that i have to insert, how do i handle that?

by random i mean something like
"01asd",
"02asdc",
"03asdce"
etch...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing the id on insert is totally irrelevant. The only question is does the value id already exist. You just need to basic "insert... on conflict (xx) do update ..."  
See [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=fe4bfc122bd232ab51bffeef73705dab). Note: the `demo` uses distinct on (id). This is strictly because the ids are randomly generated, with a high chance of generating the same id at least twice, but "on conflict" throws an exception when the if the input stream itself contains a duplicate.

```
insert into task( id, name, description) 
   select id, name, description 
     from <table name>            -- or VALUES (...)
    on conflict (id)  
       do update 
          set name = excluded.name
            , description = excluded.description
            , completed = true;
```

Comment: Yea but i saw u did a random integer id on the demo wouldn't that mean that if i insert a new task it might get as the id one already in the db which will cause an update on a task i need to insert instead?

Comment: Well 2 points. 1. The random integer was strictly so that I did not know the value;  an easily created substitute for your random string ( "01asd", "02asdc", ...). No reason just easier to create unknown values. 2.Whatever the *[conflict_target](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-insert.html)* must be defined unique.If it already exists in DB then by definition it cannot be a new task. A new task with an existing id would mean the ids are re-used making that column unsuitable for conflict resolution.  If that is the case then you need to eliminate on conflict, or choose another column(s).

Answer (score 1):

i think i found a solution
when i know the id i get is not in the db i can use default like this

'before'

```
INSERT INTO task (id,name,description,completed)
VALUES
--update
(20,'Do stuff','Stuff to do...',false), 
(21,'Do stuff','Stuff to do...',false), 
--insert
(unknown_or_random_id,'Do stuff','Stuff to do...',false), 
(unknown_or_random_id,'Do stuff','Stuff to do...',false), 
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
SET name= excluded.name etc....
```

after

```
INSERT INTO task (id,name,description,completed)
VALUES
--update
(20,'Do stuff','Stuff to do...',false), 
(21,'Do stuff','Stuff to do...',false), 
--insert
(default,'Do stuff','Stuff to do...',false), 
(default,'Do stuff','Stuff to do...',false), 
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
SET name= excluded.name etc....
```

i just wonder if there are some limitations doing that